# How to set up two UDP sockets in one executable?

Tags: c, sockets

I am new to the topic of network communication, but would like to set up an UDP server client connection, with one participant continuously broadcasting data whether anyone is listening in on it or not and two participants that start receiving and storing these information whenever they are ready to do so (It's fine if they miss what has been sent before that point). The idea is that there is no other communication than one participant sending data (fire and forget) and two participants receiving them, without any form of feedback to the sending part. For now I would like to get it running on my local host, but would like to use it on a network.

I have been looking into a solution for quite some time now and decided to have a client broadcast the file stream continuously on two separate ports so, so that the receiving two servers can bind to a port respectively without blocking each other (If there is a better way, I am open for suggestions).

So far I have been able to set up this kind of communication with one client and one server, following [these](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/syscalls.html) instructions. However, when I try to set up a second socket in my client executable, I always receive the error message ***Invalid argument*** once I reach the sendto() part.

Seeing as I have not been able to find a solution myself, yet I would like to ask for some help.

My code so far consists of the 
Client:

```
/** set up socket_1 properties */
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // set to AF_INET to force IPv4
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

/** Read address information of incoming connection */
int status;
struct addrinfo *servinfo;
if ((status = getaddrinfo(NULL, MYPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
    return 1;
}   

/** loop through all the results and bind to the first we can */
int sockfd;
struct addrinfo *p; 
for ( p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next ) { 
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        perror("listener: socket");
        continue;
    }

    //   /** Allow the reuse of a socket */
     //   if ( setsockopt( sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int) ) == -1 ){
     //       printf("[ERROR]: Failed setting reusable socket %s.\n", strerror( errno ) );
     //       exit(1);
     //   }

     //   /** Allow the reuse of a socket */
     //   if ( setsockopt( sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int) ) == -1 ){
     //       printf("[ERROR]: Failed setting reusable socket %s.\n", strerror( errno ) );
     //       exit(1);
     //   }


    break;
}
if (p == NULL) {
    printf("[ERROR]: Failed to bind broadcaster socket 1: %s.\n", strerror(errno) );
    return 2;
}


/** set up socket_2  */
// ( reuse socket_1 hints and change the port number )

/** Read address information of incoming connection */
int status_2;
struct addrinfo *servinfo_2;
if ((status_2 = getaddrinfo(NULL, MYPORT_2, &hints, &servinfo_2)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status_2));
    return 1;
}

/** loop through all the results and bind to the first we can */
int sockfd_2;
struct addrinfo *p_2;
for ( p_2 = servinfo_2; p_2 != NULL; p_2 = p_2->ai_next ) {
    if ((sockfd_2 = socket(p_2->ai_family, p_2->ai_socktype, p_2->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        perror("listener: socket");
        continue;
    }

      //  /** Allow the reuse of a socket */
      //  if ( setsockopt( sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int) ) == -1 ){
      //          printf("[ERROR]: Failed setting reusable socket %s.\n", strerror( errno ) );
      //          exit(1);
      //  }

      //  /** Allow the reuse of a socket */
      //  if ( setsockopt( sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int) ) == -1 ){
      //          printf("[ERROR]: Failed setting reusable socket %s.\n", strerror( errno ) );
      //          exit(1);
      //  }

        break;
}

if (p_2 == NULL) {
    printf("[ERROR]: Failed to bind broadcaster socket 2: %s.\n", strerror(errno) );
    return 2;
}

...
some file read/write related stuff
...

while ( /* some condition */ )
{
    if ( ( readBytes = pread( fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE, offset ) ) == -1 ){
        printf("[ERROR]: %s.\n", strerror(errno) );
        free( buf );
        close( fd );
        close( sockfd );
        exit(1);
    }


// the next line is generating the error message 
    if ( ( numbytes = sendto( sockfd, buf, readBytes, 0, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen ) ) == -1 )
    {
        perror("sender_1: sendo.\n");
        free( buf );
        close( fd );
        close( sockfd );
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( ( numbytes = sendto( sockfd_2, buf, readBytes, 0, p_2->ai_addr, p_2->ai_addrlen ) ) == -1 )
    {   
            perror("sender_2: sendo.\n");
            free( buf );
            close( fd );
            close( sockfd_2 );
            exit(1);
    }   


}

.
.
.

free( buf );
freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
freeaddrinfo(servinfo_2);

printf( "Broadcasting complete.\n" );

/** Clean what is not necessary anymore */
close( fd );
close( sockfd );

return 0;
}
```

I tried to add the reuse port and IP functionality to make sure that there is nothing blocking the setup of the new socket, but this did not solve my problem

My server side seems to work fine, but just in case I will post it here, too:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
if (argc < 2){
    printf("Please provide image Name ID.\n");
    exit(1);
}

struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *servinfo = NULL; // will point to getaddrinfo() results

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints); // make sure struct is empty 
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // don't care if IPv4 or IPv6
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;     // Use UDP protocol
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

int res;
if ((res = getaddrinfo( NULL, argv[1]/* SERVERPORT*/, &hints, &servinfo )) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(res));
    return 1;
}

/** Get socket file descriptor  */
int sockfd;
struct addrinfo *p = NULL;
// loop through all the results and make a socket
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
        p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        perror("talker: socket");
        continue;
    }

    /** Allow the reuse of an IP */
    if ( setsockopt( sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int) ) == -1 ){
            printf("[ERROR]: Failed setting reusable socket %s.\n", strerror( errno ) );  
            exit(1);
    }       

    /** Allow the reuse of a socket */
    if ( setsockopt( sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int) ) == -1 ){
            printf("[ERROR]: Failed setting reusable socket %s.\n", strerror( errno ) );  
            exit(1);
    }       


        /** Bind found socket to desired port */
    if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        close(sockfd);
        printf("[ERROR]: Failed to bind socket to desired port: %s.\n", strerror( errno ) );
        continue;
    }
break;
}

struct timeval read_timeout;
read_timeout.tv_sec = 30;
read_timeout.tv_usec = 500;
if ( setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &read_timeout, sizeof read_timeout) < 0 ){
    printf( "[ERROR]: %s.\n", strerror(errno) );
}

...
some file read/write stuff
...

while ( ( numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len ) ) != -1) 
{
.
.
.
}
printf("Done broadcasting.\n");

freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

close(sockfd);

return 0;
}
```

It would be much appreciated if anybody could provide me some help or point me into the right direction where to look for a solution.

Best regards

Comment: You can't do `freeaddrinfo(servinfo);` or `freeaddrinfo(servinfo_2);` since you later on use these values in your `sendto()` call, as in `p->ai_addr` . Your call to `sendto( sockfd_2, buf, readBytes, 0, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen )` is probably wrong anyway - `p->ai_addr` looks like an address for your own socket - surely you have to call `sendto()` with the address you actually want to send to.

Comment: @nos Thank you very much, that seems to have solved my problem. Perhaps you can help me understand why, too. The call to freeaddrinfo(servinfo) before sendto()  had no negative effect when I used the code for only one socket. Actually it worked quite fine. My understanding was, that it simply frees the memory of the servinfo pointer. As the necessary infos have been handed over to my new pointer p in the for loop I expected it to be unnecessary anymore.

Comment: yes, it frees the memory. When you then attempt to use it later on, it might work fine. Or it might not work at all. There are no guarantees as to what will happen - and as you've now seen, in some circumstances it happened to work , and in another scenario it didn't. Your `p` variable is a pointer, it points to the data that `freeaddrinfo()` will free.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: The posted code, for the client, does not compile!  Are you expecting us to guess about the missing parts?  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and debug it.

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you for your review and suggestion. 
The missing part is unrelated to the problematic part of my code. I shortened it to give a better overview of what UDP related code I have and what I am trying to do, without over stuffing it to multiple pages of code, making it harder to read.

nos, by the way, was already able to successfully identify and correct my problem. Therefore I am assuming that it must have been sufficient information. 

However I do think you have a point there and will keep it in mind for future questions.